# How to assign an object in a loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Matlab code:

```
% Performs Inner Filter Calculation using the UV absorbance spectrum.
ex_abs=absint(exabsstart:exinc:exabsend,:);
em_abs=absint(emabsstart:eminc:emabsend,:);
for i=1:length(em_abs)
    for j=1:(length(ex_abs))
        IFC(i,j)=ex_abs(j)+em_abs(i);
    end
end
Aci = A.*10.^(0.5*IFC); %This is the IFC.  
Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as index 
Undefined function or variable 'IFC'.
```

`IFC` is not being defined in the for loop, and code stops at `Aci =` statement (since `IFC` is not defined). Is there any way to define `IFC` in the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just add the following initialization before the loop:

```
 IFC=zeros(length(em_abs),length(ex_abs));
```

Comment: I need to make IFC= the ex_abs of j + the em_abs of i